# How can I debug ASP.NET Core WebAPI rejecting POST request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send a POST request to a very simple test API I've made, however it's just rejecting the request before it hits the breakpoint in the controller method and returning a 400 error.

An identical request made from Postman works fine, and the same code I'm using to call the API worked fine on another API. Ideally I'd like to compare the request made from my code and the request made from Postman, but I have no idea if that's even possible.

It's not a model issue or a routing issue.

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] User user)
{
    user.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    UserContainer.Users.Add(user);
}
```

Code calling the API:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api/");

Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PostAsync("user", new StringContent("{\"id\":\"7\",\"firstName\":\"Kanye\",\"lastName\":\"West\"}"));
task.Wait();
task.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().BeTrue();
```

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int      Id        { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string   FirstName { get; set; }
    public string   LastName  { get; set; }
}
```

**Solved**
I needed to replace this line:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PostAsync("user", new StringContent("{\"id\":\"7\",\"firstName\":\"Kanye\",\"lastName\":\"West\"}"));
```

With this:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.PostAsync("user", new StringContent("{\"id\":\"7\",\"firstName\":\"Kanye\",\"lastName\":\"West\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

Comment: Could you add `CreatedAt` in `StringContent` and see it work?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Sending `{"id":"7","firstName":"Kanye","lastName":"West"}` from Postman works though.

Comment: Your code doesn’t set the Content-Type header but Postman will do if you’ve selected JSON as the body type.

Comment: @Kirk Larkin I thought that's what I was doing with this line `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));`. Anyway, I've solved the issue now, will edit the question and show the solution.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: You’ve solved the issue by setting the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Content-Type header using the constructor of the StringContent class.